# Retrieving information using AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a database that has a column named 'wealth'. I have some code that accesses the database and finds the wealth relative to the user that is logged onto the website. It stores the value in $result. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username = strval($_GET['userName']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','id550644_uselessbutton','PRIVATE','id550644_uselessbutton');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$wealth = $row['wealth'];
echo "<p>";
echo $wealth;
echo "</p>";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
//return $wealth;
?></body>
</html>
```

I just don't know how to make it so that I can access the value of $result from my main html document through javascript. I'd like this because I want an existing javascript variable to equal $result when I trigger a function.

Thanks!

Current ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
   'type': "GET",
   'url': "getScore.php",
   'success': function (data) {
       var x = data;
    }
 });

var clicks = x;
```

Current PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username = strval($_POST['username']);
$wealth = strval($_POST['wealth']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','id550644_uselessbutton','PRIVATE','id550644_uselessbutton');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {

$sql = "UPDATE users SET wealth=".$wealth." WHERE username='".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

}

mysqli_close($con);

?></body>
</html>
```

Comment: To keep it simple, watch this video and modify it to your needs. https://youtu.be/TR0gkGbMwW0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an ajax request.

```
   $.ajax({
       'type': "GET",
       'url': <filename which has php code>,
       'success': function (data) {
           document.getElementById('<wherever you want to show results>').innerHTML = data;
        }
   });
```

**UPDATE:** You can have something similar like
PHP CODE in getScore.php

```
<?php
 //make connection
 //query the database 
 //return result in $wealth
 echo $wealth;
 ?>
```

JavaScript Code in some HTML file where your form is.

```
// Include jQuery version file in <head>
<script>
  var wealth;
  $.ajax({
       'type': "GET",
       'url': "getScore.php",
       'success': function (data) {
           wealth = data;
        }
   });
   console.log(wealth); //This will have the value returned by PHP variable
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is 'data'?

Comment: Data is whatever value your php file returns. If php prints out the string “OK”, then this data variable will contain the string “OK”. Any output that is printed/echoed will be returned to the success function.

Comment: So, how to I get this AJAX request to target the $wealth PHP variable? And how can I make it so a variable I specified in javascript is equal to the output ID of this ajax request? Thank you.

Comment: In php file, add echo $wealth. In other file where you are writing AJAX request, be sure to include jQuery and in 'success' function, var x = data; where x is the variable name.

Comment: Sorry for prologuing the chat, but mind giving me a hand on what I've done wrong? I'll edit the original question so it has my current code down the bottom.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: What errors you are getting? Where is ajax request placed? Have you included jQuery? Is ajax request inside <script></script>? You are not 'echo'-ing anything in php.

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen check this for reference: https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

Comment: FYI - declare var x outside the function to access it value. Use console.log(data) in success() to see what value you are receiving from PHP. You may be getting a JSON response as well. In that case, use proper encode/decode inside success() to get proper output.

Comment: For reference, `.ajax()` requests shouldn't have single quotes around the parameters. For example, `'type': "GET",` should be `type: "GET",` -- maybe this is why you were having errors? :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript **cannot** access a PHP variable, as JavaScript is client-side (and can only target the DOM), and PHP is server-side. In order to target a PHP variable with JavaScript, you have to use HTML as an intermediary. What I would recommend is using PHP to create a DOM element that contains the variable, then target that with JavaScript.

In this case, it looks like you're trying to target `$wealth`, so you should add a unique identifer:

```
echo "<p id='wealth'>";
echo $wealth;
echo "</p>";
```

Then target that unique identifier with JavaScript:

```
var wealth = document.getElementById('wealth').innerHTML;
```

If you'd like to target `$result` itself, you'll need to physically output its content as well. Keep in mind that if you want to **update** `$result` through JavaScript, you'll need to **post** the data back to the back-end, most likely with use of AJAX :)

**EDIT**

To have the JavaScript variable accessible on multiple pages, you have two approaches:

1) Output the target variable in a (possibly hidden) DOM element on each page, and target that ID on each page with the above script.

2) Output the target variable in the PHP script, and then use AJAX to load the PHP script as such:

PHP page:

```
<?php
  echo $wealth;
?>
```

Output page:

```
var wealth;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'yourphpscript.php',
  success: function (data) {
    wealth = data;
  }
});
```

In the AJAX post here, `data` is what is returned on a successful call to the PHP script. Essentially, it's *everything* that gets outputted if you were to visit the PHP file in your browser. Assuming that you echo the wealth variable and **only** the wealth variable on the PHP page, that is what would get passed through, and therefor, the JavaScript variable `wealth` would equal the same value as your PHP variable.

Method 1 would require you to have a fair amount of PHP on every page that you want to be able to access the JavaScript variable from, but is slightly faster as it doesn't have to make an external call.

Method 2 (with AJAX) is tidier, easily extendible to retrieve multiple variables, and also allows you to *POST* data to the server easily if you want to update the PHP variable. Note the **this method requires jQuery**, and that you will have to run the script above for each page that you want to output the `wealth` variable on.

To retrieve multiple values with method 2, you would create an array or JSON output from your PHP script, and access them as follows:

PHP output:

```
[wealth, value2]
```

JavaScript:

```
var wealth, value2;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'yourphpscript.php',
  success: function (data) {
    wealth = data[0];
    value2 = data[1];
  }
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Using var wealth = document.getElementById('wealth').innerHTML; in this document would only make the var wealth inside of this document, wouldn't it? I wouldn't be able to access it from another document. Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct to an extent -- JavaScript variables are unique to whichever page they are created on. Of course, what you *could* do is create the JavaScript variable in an external `.js` file, and include that file on every page, in a PHP header file. Then that JavaScript variable would have scope on every page :) Just make sure that you reference the variable **after** loading the external JavaScript file ;)

Comment: Interesting. Have you seen the other method that Riya suggested below? Still haven't got it to work, but it seems very easy....

Comment: I've just updated this answer to hopefully provide a clear explanation of how the AJAX approach would work, and how it can be extended as well -- please see the `Edit` section of my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

The AJAX call is asynchronous call, so you need to set the async flag false for it to wait for data to come and get assigned to x, before assigning x to clicks.

```
$.ajax({
   'type': "GET",
   'url': "getScore.php",
   **async: false,**
   'success': function (data) {
       var x = data;
    }
 });

var clicks = x;
```

Comment: Although this is true, I wouldn't personally recommend forcing ajax calls to be synchronous.